# How can I remove the spacing between these CSS rows?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create an `article` component using CSS grid. But as you can see below,  there is a large amount of vertical space between the different elements within `article` (`title`, `publication`, and `excerpt`).

When I enter a fixed height for the rows (e.g. `grid-template-rows: 10px 10px 10px`),  the spacing disappears, but as soon as I want to use something more flexible (`auto` or `minmax`), the spacing is back.

How can I use a  flexible height that will remove that vertical spacing?

[image: Screenshot of the webpage]

```css
main {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 500px;  
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .article {
      border-top: 1px solid #FF0000;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
      padding: 10px 30px;
      color:    #414a4c;
    }
    
    .publication {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      color: #757575;
```

```html
<main>
        <a href="#" class="article">
            <div class="title">
                <h2>Article title number 1</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="publication">
                <h4>The Guardian</h4>
                <h4>27 May 2021</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="exerpt">
                <p>This is an excerpt from the article this is an excerpt from the  article, etc, etc.</p>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="article">
            <div class="title">
                <h2>Article title number 2</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="publication">
                <h4>The Intercept</h4>
                <h4>27 May 2021</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="exerpt">
                <p>This is an excerpt from the article this is an excerpt from the  article, etc, etc.</p>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="article">
            <div class="title">
                <h2>Article title number 3</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="publication">
                <h4>Yes Magazine</h4>
                <h4>27 May 2021</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="exerpt">
                <p>This is an excerpt from the article this is an excerpt from the  article, etc, etc.</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </main>
```

Comment: which vertical spacing your talking about there are `3`.

Comment: I mean the spacing between the article title and the publication meta information, and between the publication meta information and the excerpt

Comment: reduce padding in article class.

Comment: I think you forget to close `.publication` tag in `css`.

Comment: remove `margin-block-end` from `.title h2`. the code will be `.title h2 { margin-block-end: 0; }`.

Comment: I tried reducing the padding in article class, but the padding in the article class adds spacing around those elements, not between them. 

And yes, editing the question to close the `.publication` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this at the top of your css -

```
*,*:after,*:before{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

It'll reset the default padding and margin of the browser, and you can learn more about box-sizing here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Codepen: https://codepen.io/bilal-23/pen/YzQzKGx
[image]